# How to count occurrences across two tables in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have two tables in Oracle 12c, goal is to count all occurrences in table2 which have Flag NULL, but also display 0 next to Names which are present in table1

table1

```
ID,Name
001,Bob
009,Alice
015,Bob
019,Bob
026,Alice
500,Rob
505,Rob
```

table2

```
ID,Flag,Timestamp
001,NULL,02/04/2016 16:33:13,991000
010,NULL,02/04/2016 16:33:14,991000
023,NULL,02/04/2016 16:33:15,991000
019,True,02/04/2016 16:33:16,991000
026,True,02/04/2016 16:33:17,991000
500,NULL,02/04/2016 16:33:18,991000
505,NULL,02/04/2016 16:33:19,991000
```

I'd like to get

```
Name,COUNT
Alice,0
Bob,1
Rob,2
```

My attempt so far is:

```
SELECT table1.Name, count(table1.Name) AS count
FROM table2
LEFT OUTER JOIN table1
ON table2.ID = table1.ID
WHERE table2.Flag IS null AND trunc(table2.Timestamp) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
GROUP BY table1.Name
```

Returning

```
Name,COUNT
Bob,1
Rob,2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace the position of `table1` with `table2` and count the `id` column of table2 (to exclude null values when the join condition is not met) .

```
SELECT table1.Name, count(table2.id) AS count
FROM table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2
ON table2.ID = table1.ID
 AND table2.Flag IS null
GROUP BY table1.Name
```

Comment: Thanks for giving it a try, I see why your solution should work, but it does not work for me. Maybe I've oversimplified my real task, there is an additional where clause restricting records from only today, no idea why it should matter, but at this point I'm totally lost

Comment: A guess? The date field is on table2 right? If so, condition on the right table of a left join should be placed only inside the on clause, not where clause. Add `and table2.datefield = trunc(sysdate)` inside there . @ninius86 When placed in the where clause the join turns into an inner join because of null values comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT table1.Name, count(table2.ID) AS count
FROM table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table2.ID = table1.ID
WHERE table2.Flag IS null
GROUP BY table1.Name
```

Comment: I've tried it, but still getting just names with non-zero count